# Displaying label when use cancel's the google sign in flow

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-signin

i'm new to iOS development and am trying to implement a google sign in in my app. I have managed to achieve the whole sign in and log out process however I am having difficulty trying to display a label if the user choses to cancel the google sign in flow instead of allowing it access.

i believe i need to use GIDSignInErrorCode to check if the user cancelled the login but i can't seem to get it to work!

Appdelegate.swift

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let err = error {
        print ("Failed to log in to FitID with Google: ", err)
        return
    }



    print ("Successfully logged in to FitID with Google", user)
    print(user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 400))
```

viewController.swift

```
IBAction func handleCustomGoogleLogin () {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

}
```

Comment: Are you getting the callback when sign in successful?

Comment: check is there delegate or not?

Comment: @Umar Yaqub You need to show a UIAlertController, not a label, so that your user can take an action based on the response received. Also, with an UIAlertController after the user clicks Yes/No or whatever button you set, you get a completion handler which enables you to take further actions. http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/

Comment: @bibscy although that will probably look better but at this moment i just wanted to show a UIlabel, i have managed to achieve the same via Facebook login using the code below:

Comment: @IBAction func handleCustomFBLogin() {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"], from: self) { ( result, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    print("FB login failed", err!)
                    
                }
                else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                    self.loginPermissionDeclined.isHidden = false //displays a message telling user why we need their facebook details
            }
}

Answer (score 1):

Jump to **GIDSignInDelegate** definition. You will see error codes.

```
/// A list of potential error codes returned from the Google Identity SDK.
```

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GIDSignInErrorCode) {

/// Indicates an unknown error has occurred.
**kGIDSignInErrorCodeUnknown = -1**,

/// Indicates a problem reading or writing to the application keychain.
**kGIDSignInErrorCodeKeychain = -2**,

/// Indicates there are no valid auth tokens in the keychain. This error code will be returned by
/// `restorePreviousSignIn` if the user has not signed in before or if they have since signed out.
**kGIDSignInErrorCodeHasNoAuthInKeychain = -4**,

/// Indicates the user canceled the sign in request.
**kGIDSignInErrorCodeCanceled = -5**,

/// Indicates an Enterprise Mobility Management related error has occurred.
**kGIDSignInErrorCodeEMM = -6**,
};